# Is there a function in plotly that is equivalent to plt.axes('scaled') in matplotlib for the aspect ratio of a graph?

Tags: matplotlib, plotly-python

I want to plot some coordinates using Plotly express because it allows me a more interactive approach, but I can not find the way to control the scale in the axis in the way I can manage with matplotlib.pyplot in one single line

```
plt.axis("scaled")
```

Could you please share some suggestions? Thanks.

Here is the code using Plotly express:

```
fig = px.scatter(coordinates_utm, x='EASTING', y='NORTHING', title=name,
                         hover_name=coordinates_utm.index, 
                         hover_data={'NORTHING':':.6f','EASTING': ':.6f'})
    
        fig.add_trace(px.scatter(coordinates_utm_lineal, x='x', y='ylineal',color_discrete_sequence=['red']).data[0])
```

Here is the code using plt:

```
fig.show()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(coordinates_utm_lineal.x,coordinates_utm_lineal.ylineal,s=2)
plt.scatter(coordinates_utm.EASTING,coordinates_utm.NORTHING, s=2)
plt.axis("scaled")
plt.show()
```

This is my current output
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, since the intent of your question is a bit unclear, is there a function in plotly that is equivalent to plt.axes('scaled') in matplotlib for the aspect ratio of a graph?

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(scaleanchor='y', scaleratio=0.5));fig.update_layout(
  autosize=False, width=400,)`

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, you didn't provide a fully reproducible example, so I'm going to create my own.

Also, I'm not really familiar with `plt.axis("scaled")`, as I usually use `plt.axis("equal")`. Reading the documentation associated to `plt.axis`, they appear to be somewhat similar. See if the following answer can satisfy your needs.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y)
fig.layout.yaxis.scaleanchor="x"
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! Sorry I didn't provide a fully reproducible example. I didn't consider it necessary. Your suggestion worked, I used it, and I added `fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=800, height=1000 )` to get the aspect I wanted.